# Google Apps Script: How do I GetID's of all the files in a specific folder, along with the names

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Relating to: Google Apps Script - Google Drive - Spreadsheet

I am completely new to programming languages.

This is what i am trying to do:

Everyday, create a folder with the syntax yymmdd

In this folder create 50 copies of the spreadsheet "MyTemplate" which is in Google Drive.

Using the following syntax for the filenames: yymmdd-01 to yymmdd-50 then get all the names and the ID's of all these spreadsheets listed in a spreadsheet called yymmdd-IDs

Here is some code I started with but I am struggling finding the right code and syntax.
Being a newbie I am having a tough time, so any help will be appreciated :)

```
    function create50copies() {
      var TemplateFile = DocsList.getFileById("0bfdbdfIr_dGNsVndBTnNNeFGtlYXchhrdhrdc");
      var filesFolder = DocsList.getFolder("My Templates");
      var d = new Date();
      var curr_date = d.getDate();
      var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
      var curr_year = d.getFullYear(); //how do I get only the last two digits?
      // var curr_year = curry_year.substring(2,2); 

      var i;

      for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
       if ((i) < 10)
       {
       TemplateFile.makeCopy("Id " + curr_year + curr_month + curr_date + "-" + "0" + i).addToFolder(filesFolder);
         var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
         Logger.log(ss.getName());
            }
       else{
       TemplateFile.makeCopy("Id " + curr_year + curr_month + curr_date + "-" + i).addToFolder(filesFolder);
           }

        // TemplateFile.makeCopy("Id " + curr_year + curr_month + curr_date + "-" + i).addToFolder(filesFolder);
      }
    }

    function getids() {
     var files = DocsList.getFilesByType('spreadsheet', 0, 50);
     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(files[i]);
       Logger.log(spreadsheet.getName());
       Logger.log(spreadsheet.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
     }

    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you use the DriveApp rather than DocsList for this. Create the containing folder; then loop using file.makeCopy(name, destination), collect the name and file id into array as you go. At end write array of names and ids to spreadsheet in one go.

Comment: What do you need to get the file ID or Spreadsheet ID? Not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the name of the files and its id while you are creating them.
Something like this

```
var today=...; //get the name of the file
var folder= ...; get the folder in DriveApps
var arnames=[];
for (var i=0;i<50;i++){
  var filename=today+i;     
  var copy=tenplate.makeCopy(filename, folder); 
  var stId=copy.getId();
  arnames.push([filename,stId]);
}

Logger.log(arnames);
```